# How to set cookie headers in NextJS13

Tags: typescript, next.js13

I am trying to serialize the refresh and access tokens from my endpoint and save them as cookies but they return undefined. Here is my code:

```
      import { NextRequest, NextResponse } from "next/server";
      import cookie from "cookie";

      export async function POST(req: NextRequest, res: NextResponse) {
     const { email, matric_number, password, porter } = await req.json();

    const userDetails = JSON.stringify({
    matric_number,
    password,
    });
    const porterDetails = JSON.stringify({
    email,
    matric_number,
    password,
    });

   const url: string =
   porter === "true"
   ? "https://endpoint.com/x/login"
   : 
   "https://endpoint.com/x/login2";
  try {
 const apiRes = await fetch(url, {
  method: "POST",
  headers: {
    Accept: "application/json",
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
  },
  body: porter === 'true' ? porterDetails : userDetails,
});

const data = await apiRes.json();
console.log(data); 
if (apiRes.status === 201 || apiRes.status === 200) {
  res.headers.set(
    "Set-Cookie",
    cookie.serialize(
      'access',
      data.access,
      {
        httpOnly: true,
        secure: process.env.NODE_ENV !== "development",
        maxAge: 60 * 30,
        sameSite: "strict",
        path: "/api/",
      }
    )
  );
  res.headers.set(
    "Set-Cookie",
    cookie.serialize(
      'refresh',
      data.refresh,
      {
        httpOnly: true,
        secure: process.env.NODE_ENV !== "development",
        maxAge: 60 * 60 * 24,
        sameSite: "strict",
        path: "/api/",
      }
    )
  );

  return NextResponse.json(
    { error: "All Done: " + data.success },
    { status: 200 }
  );
} else {
  return NextResponse.json(data, { status: apiRes.status });
}
} catch (error) {
return NextResponse.json(
  { error: "Something went wrong while logging in user" + error },
  { status: 500 }
);
}
}
```

I keep getting "Syntax error, [object object] is not valid json" in my login component. What do i do? I don't know where exactly the error is coming from. For some reason TypeScript won't let me use res.setHeaders so I am using res.headers.set indstead.

Answer (score -3):

In Next.js 13, you can set cookie headers using the setHeader method provided by the NextApiResponse object. Here's an example of how you can set cookie headers in Next.js 13:

```
import { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from 'next';

export default function handler(req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) {
  // Set the cookie headers
  res.setHeader('Set-Cookie', [
    'cookieName1=cookieValue1; Path=/; Max-Age=3600',
    'cookieName2=cookieValue2; Path=/; Max-Age=3600',
  ]);

  // Return the response
  res.status(200).json({ message: 'Cookie headers set successfully.' });
}
```

In the example above, we import the NextApiRequest and NextApiResponse types from the 'next' package. Inside the API route handler, we use the setHeader method of the NextApiResponse object to set the cookie headers.

The Set-Cookie header is set using an array of cookie strings. Each cookie string follows the format cookieName=cookieValue; options, where cookieName is the name of the cookie, cookieValue is the value of the cookie, and options are additional parameters such as Path, Max-Age, and others.

You can set multiple cookies by providing multiple strings in the Set-Cookie array.

Remember to replace 'cookieName1', 'cookieValue1', 'cookieName2', and 'cookieValue2' with your desired cookie names and values.

Once the cookie headers are set, you can return the response with the desired status code and any additional data you want to send in the response body.

Note that this example assumes you're using a Next.js API route to handle the request. The code may vary if you're setting cookies in a different context, such as server-side rendering (SSR) or client-side code.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Your answer appears likely to have been written (entirely or partially) by AI (e.g., ChatGPT). A heads-up that [posting AI-generated content is not allowed here](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831). In addition, posting AI generated content while advertising a product or service in your profile is likely to be seen by many in the community as a form of spam.  I would encourage you to to delete this answer, and likely this account.  If you'd like to contribute *your own*, quality content in the future, we'd love to have you as a part of the community.

Comment: **Readers should review this answer carefully and critically, as AI-generated information often contains fundamental errors and misinformation.** If you observe quality issues and/or have reason to believe that this answer was generated by AI, please leave feedback accordingly.

Comment: It looks like this was AI generated indeed